# How to make Django prepopulated_fields work with Chinese?

Tags: django, slug, unidecoder

The python package called unidecode which will work well for decoding Chinese characters is included in my project. But when I use it in my Django project, the prepopulated_fields didn't work with Chinese.

Version Information: django 1.86,Python 3.4

Models.py

```
# coding:utf-8

from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from unidecode import unidecode

# 类别
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        # 定义显示的名字
        verbose_name = '类别'
        verbose_name_plural = '类别'

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(unidecode(self.name))
        super(Category,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':(unidecode('name'),)}



# 文章类
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(u'标题', max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField(u'内容')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(u'发表时间', auto_now_add=True, editable=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(u'更新时间',auto_now=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)          #ForeignKey, 创建1对多关系的字段类型.

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '文章'
        verbose_name_plural = '文章'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title       #按照标题来显示每个实例，也就是一行数据
```

admin.py

```
# coding:utf-8
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article, Category ,CategoryAdmin


from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin
class SomeModelAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    pass


# 注册
admin.site.register(Article,SomeModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category,CategoryAdmin)
```

When I input some Chinese characters,I want to see the slug field be auto filled like this:
[image]

But the fact is that the slug field is not been auto filled by any characters like this in Django admin:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields):

> Set prepopulated_fields to a dictionary mapping field names to the fields it should prepopulate from:
>
> ```
> class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
> ```
>
> When set, the given fields will use a bit of JavaScript to populate from the fields assigned.

Since you have no field that corresponds to whatever the output of `unidecode('name')` is, the javascript is probably falling over.

Change it to just:

```
prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I change the code as what you said,but I still have some problems to see the results in my django admin page.I have added two pictures to explain what I need to see in admin page.